# How to load a variable within a pipeline using a property file from another freestyle project?

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins "freestyle" project which triggers a "pipeline" project (in fact my "freestyle" project is mentionned as a trigger in "Build Triggers" step of the pipeline project).

How could I grab values of variables from a ".properties" file created by each build of the "parent/freestyle" project?

Currently I have checked "archive artifacts" on the "parent/freestyle" projet and add following code to my "child/pipeline":

```
node 
{
    load "${WORKSPACE}/variables.properties"
    echo "${PARAM_FROM_TRIGGER}"
}

pipeline
{
    agent any

    stages 
    {
        stage('STEP1')
        {
            steps
            {
                sh '''
                #!/bin/bash  
                echo 'STEP 1'
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I encounter an exception after the "child/pipeline" build:

> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:
>   /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/my_pipeline/variables.properties

How could I load values from my property file?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already archiving the .properties file, I think you're looking for the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

You can use the command:

```
copyArtifacts(projectName: 'sourceproject');
```

to copy the artifacts from parent/freestyle into the workspace of child/pipeline.